# Configurable product select single each group

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I need to make a custom listing where collection of all product. I try to

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
      $col=$collection->getCollection();
      foreach($col as $c){
         $collection->load($c->getId());
         echo $collection->getName().'('.$collection->getSku().')<br>'; 
      }
```

**It's give me nice output when simple product, But configurable product then make major problem. It's show like**

```
French Cuff Cotton Twill Oxford(msj000)
French Cuff Cotton Twill Oxford(msj001)
French Cuff Cotton Twill Oxford(msj002)
Slim fit Dobby Oxford Shirt(msj003)
Slim fit Dobby Oxford Shirt(msj004)
Slim fit Dobby Oxford Shirt(msj005)
Plaid Cotton Shirt(msj006)
Plaid Cotton Shirt(msj007)
Plaid Cotton Shirt(msj008)
Sullivan Sport Coat(msj009)
Sullivan Sport Coat(msj010)
Sullivan Sport Coat(msj011)
```

**But I need like this**

```
French Cuff Cotton Twill Oxford(msj000)
Slim fit Dobby Oxford Shirt(msj003)
Plaid Cotton Shirt(msj006)
Sullivan Sport Coat(msj009)
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: what is different between the result & your require result... Question seams confuse.Please explain all.Other wise question goes to closed.

Comment: First result `French Cuff Cotton Twill Oxford` show 3 times but I need One time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **question not clearly properly to me.**

But i guss that you **want get a collection of configurable products**

Or May be want the *`a product collection which is include all products excluding configurable's child products`*.

For first requirement my suggestion to filter, collection `$col` filter by **attribute fields** *`type_id`* and ***filter value*** should be *`configurable`*,

Use **`addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code',$condition)`** for apply filter by attribute to a collection

> ```
>  $col=$collection->getCollection();
>  $col->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable');
> ```

For second requirement you need , collection `$col` filter by **attribute fields** *`visibility`* and ***filter value*** should be *`2,3,4`*,
Basically  we make **configurable associated products(child products)'s visibility**   arr *Not Visible Individually*

> ```
>  $col=$collection->getCollection();
>  $col->addAttributeToFilter('visibility','array('in'=>array(2,3,4));
> ```

***Also you do not need to load product object again by below code.it make create issue at performance.***

> ```
> $collection->load($c->getId());
>  echo $collection->getName().'('.$collection->getSku().')<br>';
> ```

Just add **`addAttributeToSelect('attribute_code')`** to collection  `$col` for getting  `sku ,name` value

> ```
> $col->addAttributeToSelect('name');
> $col->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
>
>  foreach($col as $c){
>          echo c->getName().'('.c->getSku().')<br>'; 
>       }
> ```

Comment: I need All product But when come any configurable product then Show group wise. From each group one product. My First result show 12 result where each 3 product same name(different sku).

Comment: then you can use second solution ..